# Multiple accepted answers wrongly indicated

Tags: bug, status-completed, accepted-answer, ios-app

**Description:**

In a question with an accepted answer and lots of other answers, the app shows the green tick ([image]) next to many answers, indicating that there are multiple accepted answers.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Open the left drawer, then tap Stack Overflow to go to the Stack Overflow site.
2. In the Questions tab, tap the button next to the search field above the questions, then choose Sort by Votes.
3. Select the first question (i.e. [Why is processing a sorted array faster than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/1402846)).
4. Go to the Answers Tab, then look for the green tick next to the answers.

**Actual Results:**

There are more than one answers that has a green tick.

**Expected Results:**

Only the accepted answer should ha­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­ve the green tick.

**Environment:**

- Stack Exchange iOS App v0.1.26
- iPhone 5
- iOS 7.1

**Note:**

1. I do not have to log in to see this bug.
2. I tried rebooting my phone, and reinstalling the app. I still see the bug.

Comment: I am unable to replicate this.  I've tried 7.0.6 on a 4S, and 7.1 in the 5S simulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be fixed in version 0.1.27.

Comment: Not sure why I'm the only one not seeing the bug...

Comment: Verified fixed in v0.1.27.