# Inline image alignment issue for app and mobile web

Tags: bug, ios-app, mobile-web

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226102/339911) contains image inside text, but appearance is differ on full site and mobile web/app.

1. iOS app:

   > [image: ios]
2. Full site:

   > [image: full site]
3. Mobile web:

   > [image: mobile web]
4. Android-app:

   > [image: android-app]

My thoughts that only full site's and android-app's alignment is correct.

---

- App Version: 1.6.1.2
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.1.1 (Build 14B100)

Comment: Hmm... The iOS app uses mobile rules (`max-width: 90%; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`) and the Android app uses full site rules (`max-width: 100%`).  I don't know how common inline images are in posts, but for most cases, I feel like the mobile web version works best for the app.

Comment: @BrianNickel [related question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284691/339911)